# How to properly format dates in Google Sheets or Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, date, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet I need to make in Google Sheets. The source of some of the data is exported to an Excel sheet. The data arrives in a `dd/mm/yyyy` format and I need to display it in a `MON d` format (Ex Sep 5).

The problem is both excel and sheets look at the date that arrives and think it is mm/dd/yyyy.

For example, 02/08/2022 is believed to be Febuary 8 even though it should be Aug 2. The problem then arises that neither of these platforms end up knowing how to convert this to Aug 2 and I end up having to do this manually.

**Does anyone know how to get around this?**

I have tried adjusting the format of the date, as well as using DateValue to convert (this fails since it understands the date as mm/dd/yyyy even when it is dd/mm/yyyy).

Any leads would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Does Excel handle date formatting the same way as Googlesheets? If not, then work in one only and do a final export to the other.

Comment: do you want formula that will convert 02/08/2022 into Aug 2?

Comment: @SolarMike from what I have seen it seems to be similar. Tried that avenue already

Comment: @player0 Ideally a format, but if a formula is the only way to go, then yes. Currently it takes the text and either leaves it in the format it comes (not ideal) or changes it to the incorrect date altogether (bad)

Comment: In either program, you need to inform the program of the date format at the time of **import**ing the file.  If you merely **Open** the file, the program will interpret the values according to your windows regional settings.  If your original file is a CSV file, then **import** into Excel using either Power Query or the Legacy import wizard and specify the date type at that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google Sheets, choose **File > Settings > Locale** and select a locale that uses the `dd/mm/yyyy` date format, *before* importing the data. You can then format the date column the way you prefer.

Comment: Is this for excel, sheets or both? With excel the data is exported from a website, and then copied/pasted into sheets

Comment: The answer is for Google Sheets. I am afraid that your process description remains unclear. Add the necessary details in the _question_.

Answer (score 0):

in gs:

```
=TEXT(REGEXREPLACE(A1&""; "(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)"; "$1/$1/$3"); "mmm d")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following and **format the result to your liking**

```
=INDEX(IF(ISNUMBER(U2:U5),U2:U5,
           IF(U2:U5=DATEVALUE("1899-12-30"),, 
               (MID(U2:U5,4,3)&LEFT(U2:U5,3)&RIGHT(U2:U5,4))*1)))
```

*(**Do adjust the formula** according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]

Functions used:

- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`DATEVALUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093039)
- [`ISNUMBER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093296)
- [`TRUNC`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093588)
- [`MID`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093588)
- [`LEFT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094079)
- [`RIGHT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094087)

Answer (score 0):

Well, for a formulaic solution, if the date is in A1, then the following places the correct date in B1:

```
=DATEVALUE(TEXT(A1,"DD/MM/YYYY"))
```

The `TEXT` function makes a string that will be the same form as your imported string out of the date produced during import. `DATEVALUE` then gives the proper date you desired.

The trick is in the `TEXT` step in which you reverse month and day in the string for `DATEVALUE`.

Naturally, instead of a helper column, it could just be wrapped around any reference to a date from column A, though one would have to remember to do so for all the years the spreadsheet is in use.

If you are importing, not just opening a .CSV file via `File|Open` and going from there, you have an opportunity to solve all your problems. You use the Ribbon menuing system's Data menu, select the very leftmost thing, `Get Data` and from the (no arguing THIS isn't a menu) menu that drops down, `Legacy Wizards`, then finally `From Text (Legacy)` which will open the old Excel Import Wizard. (You may notice this is very like the `Data|Text to Columns` Ribbon menu choice and that is because that choice is the old wizard minus the steps at the start that go looking to another file for the data because it knows, by law, that it has to already be in the spreadsheet... in other words, it looks the same because it IS the same.)

Then make selections for the first couple dialogs it presents you to get to the dialog in which you tell it to import columns as whatever:  general (let Excel decide), text, date, and do not import. Choose `Date` and make the selection of `DMY` to import them properly as you desire them to be so you are never presented with the problem at all.

As you might guess, you can use the abbreviated wizard via the "Text to Columns" feature to do the same thing after import when you see they are reversed. Since it is a single column of data, the result will overwrite the original simplifying your work.

Why does this happen at all? Well, the "locale" folks have the idea. When Excel imports numbers that are in a form it recognizes could be a date, it looks to the operating system settings for the selected ways dates are understood. So if your operating system believes a date should be displayed "Month Day, Year" and Excel has a set of data it thinks fits that mold, it will convert them all using it. So you get those Feb 8's rather than Aug 2's.

Interestingly, it does two other things of note:

1. It looks at 8, count 'em, 8 rows of data to decide the data fits the pattern. Even with 1,000,000 rows to import, it looks at... 8.
2. Then it does them ALL as if God himself wrote the "8"... and dates like 25/03/2022 get imported as text not a real date, because they (oh, obviously) can't be dates... "25" can't be a month!

It IS possible to change settings (DEEP settings) to make Excel consider X number of rows in a data set before deciding such things. I found them here, on the internet, once upon a time, though I shouldn't like trying to find them again. It will consider up to a million rows in such an import, but... that'd make it pret-ty slow. And that's a million rows for EACH data column. I won't even say that "adds up" - I'll point out it "multiplies up."

Another technique is to add some number of starting rows to force the desired pattern onto the import. I've heard it works in TIME column imports so it ought to in DATE column imports but I've not verified such.

My bet is you will find the use of the "Text to Columns" feature of most use if you can use a hands-on approach - it does require literal action on your part, but is a fast operation. If you will see others using the spreadsheet though... well, you need a formulaic solution or a VBA one (macro with button for them to have some fun clicking as their reward for doing what they were trained to do instead of complaining to the boss you make bad spreadsheets). For a formulaic solution, the above formula is simple.

Last thought though:  there's no error-checking and error-overcoming in it. So a date like "25/03/2022" in the data that imported as literal text is a problem. For handling the latter, an up-to-date approach could be:

```
=IF(TYPE(A1)=1,DATEVALUE(TEXT(A1,"dd/mm/yyyy")),DATE(INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"/"),1,3),INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"/"),1,2),INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"/"),1,1)))
```

in which the `DATE(etc.` portion handles finding text of the "25/03/2022" kind. Lots of less up-to-date ways to split the text Excel would have placed in the column, but since demonstrating what to do if it existed was the point, I took the easy way out. (Tried for a simple version but it wouldn't take `INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"/"),1,{3,2,1})` from me for the input parameters to `DATE`.) `TYPE` will give a 1 if Excel imported a datum as a date (number), and a 2 if brought in as text. If empty or strange strings could exist, you'll need to deal with what those present you as well.